# Is it possible to use the volatile keyword with Cudafy.NET?

Tags: cudafy.net

I need to declare an array passed to a function as volatile, does Cudafy.NET support this?

For example (in C#):

```
[Cudafy]
private static void doStuffOnGPU(GThread thread, volatile int[] output)
{
  //do a whole bunch of stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, as of November 26, 2016, Cudafy.NET does not support the volatile keyword.  However, you can tricksify Cudafy.NET into allowing it in certain circumstances.

Ex:

```
//declare a dummy in global scope
public static int[] volatileArray = new int[256];
[Cudafy]
private static void doStuffOnGPU(GThread thread, int[] output)
{
  //use the GThread.InsertCode() function to declare in CUDA
  GThread.InsertCode("__shared__ volatile int volatileArray[256];");
  //do a whole bunch of stuff
}
```

This code will use the global declaration when run serially for testing and will use the volatile declaration on the GPU.